# JQuery AJAX request behaving synchronous

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

This is similar to the "answered" question
[JQuery AJAX request behaving synchronous for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383247/jquery-ajax-request-behaving-synchronous-for-unknown-reason)

I believe that the actual issue with parallel execution observed by MGM has been overlooked and actually there is a problem with $.get/$.ajax executed in parallel.

Look at the snippet below:

```
$(function() {
    $(".dd").each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        $.get("test.txt", function(data) {
            obj.html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

It loads a file (asynchronously I would expect) and displays it (synchronously of course).

However, the code executes differently during the first page load and on page refresh. I am monitoring the requests to the server using firebug Net panel in Firefox 4.0 on Windows. On the first page load (or when refreshed using Ctrl-F5) I can see on the Net panel that multiple requests to the "test.txt" start at the same time and the Net acivity mostly overlapps.

This part works as expected. The result may be processed in the browser one by one, but the requests to the server are performed in parallel.

[image: image:initial load]

It is completly different story when user presses F5 to refresh the page. Suddenly parallelism is gone. And same web page loads "test.txt" one by one.

[image: image: Subsequent refresh]

It becomes even more clear if I replace data display (obj.html(data);) with a simple alert: alert(data); On initial page load I get multiple alert messages on the screen at the same time. Subsequent refreshes (F5) clearly demonstrate that while one alert message is on screen no other downloads are performed (I can remove the file to see next "$.get" to fail).

So in fact the $.get does not perform async. calls to the server.

Any ideas on why this happening?

P.S. Sorry system does not allow me to post images use provided URL to see the screenshots.

Comment: You are confusing asynchronous and parallel execution. Asynchronous means that the browser doesn't block while waiting for the server request. The browser instance is a single threaded process, it can't do anything in parallel. Alert is always a blocking call, so of course it can't download anything while the alert box is up. The difference between your initial load and refresh is probably the browser is re-validating its cache when you hit refresh, which is what it is supposed to do. Try using a $.ajax({ sync: true }) call with a large list of .dd and you'll see your browser freeze up.

Comment: "browser instance" - not sure what exactly you refer by that, but the browser is multi threaded. JavaScript execution always performed in a single thread. You are correct on that.
Alert is browser implementation and though it blocks JavaScript execution it does not have to be blocking in regard to the browser processing.

Comment: During the initial page loading, when the first alert is on screen, all requests are get processed and files get loaded. If I remove the file while first alert is on screen I do not get any errors and can see other alerts. (older browsers behaviour is different and alert can actually block everything)

Comment: The difference between initial load and refresh is what confuses me.
During the refresh browser does not even start the next ajax request until the previuos is completely processed.

I do not think it is as simple as "re-validating its cache" because the browser has other threads to do the housekeeping and should not be affecting javaScript engine thread. Besides, other resources (images, javascript files) are been downloaded in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

After various testing I tend to agree that $.get/$.ajax works asynchronous as supposed to.

The same code works perfectly asynchronous, provided the server does not respond immediatly but takes some time to process the requests.
With artificial delay on the server, the logs collected on the server show that the requests are coming in parallel regardless if it is initial page load or subsequent refreshes. Firebug shows the same: the calls to server are overlapping.

The shorter requests are seem to be too quick and the browser "decides" to process the response before initiating the next call.

As has been noted, asynchronous does not mean to be exactly in parallel.